# How to Translate Forces Between Points?

Tags: forces, kinematics

Consider a force $\vec{F}$ acting at distance $\vec{r}$ from a center of mass $CoM$ . Is it possible to somehow express the forces acting on $CoM$ from the known variables?

The torque will obviously stay the same ($\vec{\tau} = \vec{r} \times \vec{F}$) but can you express $\vec{F_{out}}$ in terms of the known variables so that the two systems — the one with only $\vec{F}$, and the one with only $\vec{F_{out}}$ are equivalent / will behave the same?

**The vectors are in three dimensions.**

Keep in mind, I do not know if this is a legitimate question.

[image]

Comment: Vectors like forces are things that have a *magnitude* and a *direction*, but they do not intrinsically have a *position* in space that they exist in -- the idea of specifying different vectors at different points in space is what we would call a *vector field*, for example if you specify the wind speed and direction at every point on a map. If you are talking about a vector field, then you have to define "downstream" before you can translate a vector downstream, but afterwards it is a well-behaved operation. If you are talking about individual vectors then I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: @CRDrost Well it kind of goes like this --- I have a euler lagrange system where the linear kinetic energy is defined as the linear velocity in each spatial axis of the center of mass. I have defined the center of mass in terms of the position where the force F is acting on (the end of $\vec{r}$). So I wonder if it is possible to instead of expressing the center of mass in terms of the point where the force is acting on, express the forces that are acting on the center of mass. (express the forces acting on the center of mass from the forces acting on the end of $\vec{r}$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forces (as a concept) act along a line in space called the line of action. But a force vector (as three components) does not carry any location information on its own. To describe a physical fore you not only need the force vector, but also the equipollent torque that force has about the measuring point.

Two force systems are equipollent *only* if their forces are equal and the torques about some point are equal also in the same coordinate frame.

This means that a force $\vec{F}$ acting on a point located at $\vec{r}$ from the center of mass, is equipollent to the same force $\vec{F}$ acting through the center of mass *and* the torque $\vec{\tau} = \vec{r} \times \vec{F}$ acting on the body.

Let us designate the point where the force acts *A* and the center of mass *C*. You can now write

$$ \begin{aligned}
\vec{F}_B & = \vec{F}_A \\
\vec{\tau}_B & = \vec{\tau}_A + \vec{r}_{A/B} \times \vec{F}_A
\end{aligned} \;\tag{1}$$

In your case, $\vec{\tau}_A =0$ since the line of action passes through *A*.

The above is necessary in order to apply Newton's third law. In this context, think of what force is needed at the support of a beam *B* when an applied force acts through *A*.

[image: img]

It is obvious that the solution has to be $\vec{F}_B = \vec{F}_A$, as well as the torque $\vec{\tau}_B = \vec{r}_{A/B} \times \vec{F}_A$ which means that **forces transform between points identically, and torques obey the law of moments.**

Comment: alright but so what is $F_{out}$ then lol?

Comment: $F_{out} = F$,  I thought I made it clear.

Comment: sorry for my language but holy fucking shit. realizing this shit still works in my case (i haven't said everything) changes everything. holy fuck. because i am making a simulation and i just tried this and it literally fucking saved me 127k characters of pure equation of motions. I wrote a fucking program to generate them. This eliminates everything. thanks, even though you said something i already knew it helped somehow. seriously thanks a lot.

Comment: I am legitimately jumping out of joy